# como ver siempre el final de la pagina en un Text usando Python Tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter, text, textarea

Estoy trabajando en Python con Tkinter con un text

```
self.chat_historial_area = Text(self.canvas, width=42, height=16, fg="white", bg="gray20")
```

Entonces le llega al self.chat_historial_area un texto muy largo y lo que yo necesito es que se situé en la ultima parte del texto. por que al momento de hacer:

```
self.chat_historial_area.delete("1.0", "end")
self.chat_historial_area.insert(END, " Texto muy largo "*1000)
```

Se situa siempre al inicio del texto y me toca hacer scroll para ver el final.

Alguien me puede ayudar para que siempre que se inserte el texto este se muestre en la ultima parte.

Comment: Usa el método Text.see(index) (lo cual hace visible la posición index en el text) usando "end" o tkinter.END como index. "end" significa, en este caso, el final del texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias caballero... Me funciono perfectamente.